# Minecraft all mob farm not working on 1.19

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have an all mob farm in my survival world created in 1.18 version. Now, when I updated the world into 1.19 the farm stopped working. I AFKed like 1 hr and didn't get anything. Can you help me to solve this problem? (playing on Minecraft Java edition 1.19 latest release) and I use mods like Soudium, Litium, etc.

Video link:

Some screen shots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Have you tried removing any mods?

Comment: I doubt that these mods have anything to do with that, but please do make sure that they don't. Also, it's surprising that your game starts, considering that your Clumps mod appears to be for forge and not for fabric like the others.

Comment: Apart from that, where did you AFK? If you stood on the ground next to it, pillar up for ~90 blocks on top of your spawner, and try to AFK there (empty inventory before, in case you fall down).